# Rails type database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called Notification. This table has the following fields **:id , :user_id , :foreign_id , :type**

I want to associate Notifications with other tables like Friend , Quiz , Sport , Trip using the foreign key field **:foreign_id**, so that I can store different types of notifications in a generic way. I would like to store what type of notification in the :type database column such as "Friend" or "Quiz" and so on.

What is the best way to achieve something like this in Rails?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is what you are looking for is called [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 1):

You can store class name of the associated object as a string in `object_type` (or however you name it) field, that allows you to retrieve associated object like that:

```
# create new notification for quiz
Notification.create(user_id: user.id, foreign_id: quiz.id, object_type: quiz.class.to_s)

# load associated object for notification
associated_object = notification.object_type.constantize.find(notification.foreign_id)
```

Comment: Are the column names :foreign_id , :object_type built-in conventions?

Comment: No, they aren't. In fact you'd better use Polymorphic Associations as Art Shayderov suggested. It will be a better solution. Approach I suggested is more robust and may be not as good in actual project. See [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) for nice explanation of polymorphic associations.